# Can I damage the Bambu A1 Mini by selecting the wrong nozzle size in settings?

Tags: nozzle, bambu-lab-a1-mini

I have a Bambu A1 Mini.  My daughter often prints with it, and enjoys doing all of the little tasks involved with printing like switching nozzles.  She does the process proficiently while I observe, but I often have to remind her to go into the maintenance menu to change the nozzle setting afterwards.  Is there any damage that can be done by failing to properly set that configuration?

Comment: Mea culpa: My daughter has a Bambu A1 Mini.  I often print with it. This is how things go ;-)  I am, of course, in charge of maintenance until she's ready for that.